# Apache and RewriteRule priorities

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect articles from my blog to their english version.

Basically, an article /my/article is in french. But you can access the english version at /en/my/article. I need to redirect to this url if the user is not french.

I made this rule in my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^fr [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

When I'm going to /my/articles I'm actually redirected to /en/index.php.
I think it's because of the Wordpress default redirection:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What's the order of these rules?

Comment: also, try changing [L,R] to just [R]

Comment: I put this rule at the beginning of my .htaccess

Comment: I changed from [L,R] to just [R] and I get this :

Found

The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: So, you have your rule at the beginning and wordpress's rule at the end? Are they in the same file?

Comment: Absolutely ! Here's the file: http://pastium.org/view/8a23279872e04753b84c93923a99c00d

Comment: What happens if you remove [R] completely from that same line?

Comment: Then I have an Internal server error.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that I have an infinite redirection loop (says my browser) when I use [L,R]. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Put [L,R] again and try adding "RewriteBase /" above the RewriteCond. I think you maybe keep adding /en/ infinitely

Answer (score 0):

Update the wp_options table in your WordPress database. Search for "/my/" in wp_options and replace all instances of it with "/en/".

Comment: Basically, WordPress thinks your website is still located at wordpress/my/. Change it to wordpress/en/ (if you haven't already) for WordPRess to recognize the new URL.